# File created by program removed when pushing to heroku app

Tags: python, git, heroku

I have a file "config.json" created when my python script runs. Everytime I push a new commit to heroku it removes that config.json file from the heroku app. Is there anyway I can get git to not remove config.json when I push from remote? I don't want it removed since the contents of config.json change when the script runs.

Answer (score -1):

I created an AWS profile and stored my file in an S3 bucket. I then download and read/write the file, then finally save changes to my bucket.